# How can I parse the output from a JDateChooser field into something useful?

Tags: simpledateformat, parseexception, jdatechooser

When I get the date from my JDateChooser I get something like:

Fri Nov 02 23:20:32 EST 2012

I've tried using SimpleDateFormat but I get an error saying it's unparseable.

I need the date in format: "yyyy-MM-dd"

This is the API of the JDateChooser I'm using: http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have been using SimpleDateFormat incorrectly.

The solution is:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String startDateString = dateFormat.format(projectStartDateJDateChooser.getDate());
```